# Bounds on a mapping from unit disc to left half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

I've recently started studying for qualifying exams and have been having trouble with the following question: Let $f$ be a nonconstant analytic function on $\mathbb{D}$ such that $f (\mathbb{D}) \subset \{z \in \mathbb{C}: Re(z)<0\}$ with $f(0)=-1$. Prove that for any $z \in \mathbb{D}$
$$
\frac{1-|z|}{1+|z|} \leq |f(z)| \leq \frac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}
$$

I have been able to show that I only need to prove one side of the inequality since 1/f(z) also satisfies the hypothesis, but I haven't been able to figure out anything meaningful beyond that. Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Consider the Schwarz lemma. That could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Compose with a fractional linear transformation taking the left half plane to the unit disk.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I have composed $f$ with $\frac{z+1}{z-1}$ and am getting $\frac{|f(z)+1|}{|f(z)-1|} \leq |z|$ by the Schwarz Lemma. Does it just boil down to manipulating the inequality from here?

Comment: Actually, nevermind. I was able to get it from there. My brain wasn't working right on manipulating the inequality. Thank you very much.