# Bounds for analytic map from unit disk to right half-plane

Tags: complex-analysis, conformal-geometry

As discussed at [Bounds on a mapping from unit disc to left half plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/438360/bounds-on-a-mapping-from-unit-disc-to-left-half-plane), for analytic map $f$ from unit disk to left or right half plane with $f(0)=\pm 1$ (depends on left or right half-plane), we must have
\begin{align*}
\dfrac{1-|z|}{1+|z|}\leq |f(z)|\leq \dfrac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}.
\end{align*}
I understand we should have $\dfrac{|f(z)-1|}{|f(z)+1|}\leq |z|$ in case of right half-plane, but how we can deduce $|f(z)|\leq \dfrac{1+|z|}{1-|z|}$ from there?

Comment: $|f(z)-1|\geq |f(z)|-1$ and  $|f(z)+1|\leq |f(z)|+1$. After this you only need simple high school Algebra.

Comment: Did you check for duplicates?

Comment: @geetha290krm ah I was thinking too much to have the inverse of $\frac{z-1}{z+1}$ to be applied inside the bracket, thank you. Yes I checked.